# Jquery disable is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input[name='data[Store][id][]']").change(function () {
if ($("input[name='data[Store][id][]']").is(':checked')) {
        var input_value = parseFloat($(this).val());
        var brand= $(this).closest('tr').find('#brand').text();


        var number1 = $(this).closest('tr').find('input[name="data[store][stock_received][]"]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');

        }else{
        var number1 = $(this).closest('tr').find('input[name="data[store][stock_received][]"]').prop("disabled", false);

        }

 });
});
</script>
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>      

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input id='tmpid' name="data[store][stock_received][]" ></td>       
    <td><input type='checkbox' name='data[Store][id][]'></td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><input id='tmpid' name="data[store][stock_received][]"></td>        
    <td><input type='checkbox' name='data[Store][id][]'></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input id='tmpid' name="data[store][stock_received][]"></td>        
    <td><input type='checkbox' name='data[Store][id][]'></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input id='tmpid' name="data[store][stock_received][]"></td>        
    <td><input type='checkbox' name='data[Store][id][]'></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input id='tmpid' name="data[store][stock_received][]"></td>        
    <td><input type='checkbox' name='data[Store][id][]'></td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

jquery disable is not working properly and I want to  disable `id=tmpid` near near `name='data[Store][id][]'`.
Currently i m using `name='data[store][stock_received][]'` name near `name='data[Store][id][]'`.
For individual check box its working fine . If I select all then i uncheck then its not working properly

Comment: You need to replace `attr` with `prop`

Comment: how to disable using tmpid ..

Comment: You can't have more than one element with the same id. Ids **must** be unique. Use a class instead.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Lpfqua0w/

Comment: check box is not working properly .

Comment: checkbox value is on or off. You are using parseFloat() on a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)ID should be unique

2)You are using parseFloat() on an string

3)`$("input[name='data[Store][id][]']").is(':checked')` seems in correct
should be `$(this).is(":checked")`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input[name='data[Store][id][]']").change(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      var input_value = $(this).val();
      var brand = $(this).closest('tr').find('#brand').text();


      var number1 = $(this).closest('tr').find('input[name="data[store][stock_received][]"]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');

    } else {
      var number1 = $(this).closest('tr').find('input[name="data[store][stock_received][]"]').prop("disabled", false);

    }

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input class='tmpid' name="data[store][stock_received][]">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type='checkbox' name='data[Store][id][]'>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input class='tmpid' name="data[store][stock_received][]">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type='checkbox' name='data[Store][id][]'>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input class='tmpid' name="data[store][stock_received][]">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type='checkbox' name='data[Store][id][]'>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input class='tmpid' name="data[store][stock_received][]">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type='checkbox' name='data[Store][id][]'>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input class='tmpid' name="data[store][stock_received][]">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type='checkbox' name='data[Store][id][]'>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```